# Order by 2 columns and rand()

Tags: mysql

I have this structure of DB:

```
|id|name|vip|price|
```

And this content:

```
|id|name |vip|price|
|1 |note1|1  |10000|
|2 |note2|0  |13000|
|3 |note3|0  |50000|
|4 |note4|1  |12000|
|5 |note5|0  |500  |
```

In site I have 3 types of sorting - by id, by price, by name.

But first of all I must show VIP notes and they must order by rand :)

Such like as: 
`SELECT * FROM notes ORDER BY vip DESC, ORDER BY price ASC`

But VIP notes also must sort by rand :)

Can I make this by 1 request to DB?

Comment: Do you want to sort vip notes by rand, but sort normal notes by price?

Comment: of what use would be sorting `VIP desc` **AND** `vip RAND()`? you can't have the field sorted two different ways.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM notes ORDER BY vip DESC, price ASC`. Don't add `ORDER BY` twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to achieve the specified resultset in a single query. (If we're understanding the specification; there appears to be a large degree of confusion as to the actual spec.)

If `vip` column is integer, and contains values 0 and 1, and the "VIP" rows are the rows with `vip=1`, and you want those rows returned first (before the "non-VIP" rows, but you want those returned in a pseudo-"random" order, followed by the "non-VIP" rows (`vip=0`) in order by `price`

One way to achieve that would be use an `ORDER BY` clause like this:

```
SELECT n.*
  FROM notes n
 ORDER BY IF(n.vip, RAND(), NULL), n.price
```

NOTE: replace `n.price` with `n.id` or `n.name` to order "by id" or "by name", respectively, instead of "by price".

Answer (score 4):

I think you want:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM notes 
ORDER BY vip DESC, 
         price ASC,
         RAND()
```

Beware though there can be a high performance cost for ordering by rand on larger tables.

Comment: Thank you!! Thats just I was looking for :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM notes ORDER BY price DESC, price ASC, RAND(vip);
```

Comment: That will seed RAND(), not order the vip rows by rand().

Comment: @VMai Technically it will order the vip rows by rand(), but you'll get the same pattern of number generation every call.

Comment: This query will always have a random sort because random is included in the ORDER by. If you want only a query that shows random comments, SELECT * FROM notes ORDER BY RAND(). You will need two separate queries.

Comment: @user2200429 We know how RAND() works, but why have you seeded it RAND(vip)?

Comment: "Seeding" RAND to "vip" so that it randomizes that column. Not necessary, but can be an additional parameter for randomization.

Comment: -1. This doesn't make sense. Specifying `price` as both the first and second expression in the ORDER BY clause doesn't make sense. And specifying an expression as a seed value for the `RAND()` function does _not_ randomize "by that" expression. There's only two values for `vip` shown in the example data, 1 and 0. `RAND(1)` will return the _same_ value every time, not a random value.